# Reuse broken up plaster wall

Tags: plaster

I have a banister that is screwed into a plaster wall. The screws have come out of the wall and the plaster is all broken up. I know how to put stuff over the broken up plaster to make it smooth, but I'd like to be able to use that same exact spot to drill the banister screws back in.

Do I buy plaster and use that to fill in the broken plaster so that I can drill into the same area again?[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

You should fill the hole, it's not that large, so you could just handle it with patching plaster or setting compound.

As for the banister, you are not supposed to anchor into plaster, ... for this reason. It doesn't hold well, and can crumble or tear out.  You need to secure anything that needs more than construction adhesive into wood framing.

Comment: Yup, the screws holding up the banister should go into studs, no matter what kind of material the wall is covered with. The banister will be expected to bear the full weight of a falling adult, should he slip while climbing/descending the stairs.

Comment: Ideally a stud or cabinet blocking is where you want to secure it.... but in theory if there is 3+ fasteners at each bracket, heavy duty toggle bolts could hit the weight minimum.   I would consider them more for as in-addition to stud secured brackets, if you needed to span distance without being able to hit the framing for some good reason.  Certainly not with plaster walls though, that is a non-option completely.